# What is number of permutations under these conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

Example:
Let's say you have $6$ elements (letters a,b,c,d,e,f) and $10$ places where to put them. Each element can occur from $0$ to maximum $4$ times in a given word. How many different words can you construct from those $6$ letters?

I have to find the answer for $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$ and $10$ places and for $5$ or $6$ letters.

I should add that this is not homework or any school related assignment and I am not briliant in mathematics. I know how to solve basic combinatorics problems but this is out of my reach. I can do it for two smallest numbers of boxes just by removing unwanted combinations from total number of all possible words, but than I get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you mean you have 6 element types, a through f, each of which has 1 to 4 instances? Is there a limit on the capacity of individual places to put them? I.e., if you had 4 instances of each type - 24 in all - would they all fit in 1 place?

Comment: No. You just have those 6 letters and have to construct 10 letter word.

Comment: When you're stuck like this, start small and then infer from the easier examples what to do with the harder ones. Have you tried with a few smaller sets of letters with no restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose you only want to count how many word *types* there are.

By "types" I mean words with specific numbers of "a"s, "b"s, "c"s, "d"s, "e"s and "f"s.

So, for example the 10 letter word **abbdceefaa** would be of type $a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1$ and incidentally is one of your valid words, this will be our example word type throughout.

How might we generate word types? Let's not worry for the moment about how long the word must be (in fact you state in your question that you want to be able to count words of other lengths too so this shouldn't be a problem), we must have at least $1$ of each letter and at most $4$, so let's lay that out: we can have

$$\begin{align}&(a^1 \text{ or } a^2 \text{ or } a^3 \text{ or } a^4) \text{ and } (b^1 \text{ or } b^2 \text{ or } b^3 \text{ or } b^4) \text{ and }\\&
(c^1 \text{ or } c^2 \text{ or } c^3 \text{ or } c^4) \text{ and } (d^1 \text{ or } d^2 \text{ or } d^3 \text{ or } d^4) \text{ and }\\&
(e^1 \text{ or } e^2 \text{ or } e^3 \text{ or } e^4) \text{ and } (f^1 \text{ or } f^2 \text{ or } f^3 \text{ or } f^4)
\end{align}$$

now it seems reasonable that in order to look at all combinations of number of each letter we use $+$ instead of "or" and $\cdot$ instead of "and", giving us

$$\begin{align}&(a^1 + a^2 + a^3 + a^4)\cdot (b^1 + b^2 + b^3 + b^4)\cdot\\&
(c^1 + c^2 + c^3 + c^4)\cdot (d^1 + d^2 + d^3 + d^4)\cdot\\&
(e^1 + e^2 + e^3 + e^4)\cdot (f^1 + f^2 + f^3 + f^4)
\end{align}$$

so if we imagine multiplying this out we can hopefully convince ourselves that you will generate each valid word type of length $6$ up to length $24$, our example word type $a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1$ comes from multiplying the $a^3$ term from the first set of brackets with the $b^2$ term from the second set of brackets, the $c^1$ term from the third set of brackets and so forth i.e.

$$\begin{align}&(a^1 + a^2 + \bbox[yellow]{a^3} + a^4)(b^1 + \bbox[yellow]{b^2} + b^3 + b^4)\\&
(\bbox[yellow]{c^1} + c^2 + c^3 + c^4)(\bbox[yellow]{d^1} + d^2 + d^3 + d^4)\\&
(e^1 + \bbox[yellow]{e^2} + e^3 + e^4)(\bbox[yellow]{f^1} + f^2 + f^3 + f^4) = \ldots +\: \bbox[yellow]{a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1}\:+ \ldots
\end{align}$$

Now, how many words of type $a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1$ are there?

Well this is a simple combinatorics exercise of arrangements of objects where some are identical and yields for this case

$$\frac{10!}{3!\,2!\,1!\,1!\,2!\,1!}$$

It would be really nice if this were our coefficient of $a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1$ because then we could add up all the coefficients of the $10$ letter words we generate above with our polynomial multiplication and we would have our answer.

So we want our right hand side term to look like

$$\ldots +\: \frac{10!}{3!\,2!\,1!\,1!\,2!\,1!}a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1\: + \ldots$$

or

$$\ldots\: + 10!\frac{a^3}{3!}\frac{b^2}{2!}\frac{c^1}{1!}\frac{d^1}{1!}\frac{e^2}{2!}\frac{f^1}{1!} +\: \ldots$$

we can **almost** do this if we replace each letter in our polynomial multiplication as below

$$\begin{align}&\left(\frac{a^1}{1!}+\frac{a^2}{2!}+\frac{a^3}{3!}+\frac{a^4}{4!}\right)\left(\frac{b^1}{1!}+\frac{b^2}{2!}+\frac{b^3}{3!}+\frac{b^4}{4!}\right)\\&\left(\frac{c^1}{1!}+\frac{c^2}{2!}+\frac{c^3}{3!}+\frac{c^4}{4!}\right)\left(\frac{d^1}{1!}+\frac{d^2}{2!}+\frac{d^3}{3!}+\frac{d^4}{4!}\right)\\&\left(\frac{e^1}{1!}+\frac{e^2}{2!}+\frac{e^3}{3!}+\frac{e^4}{4!}\right)\left(\frac{f^1}{1!}+\frac{f^2}{2!}+\frac{f^3}{3!}+\frac{f^4}{4!}\right)\\& = \ldots +\: \frac{a^3}{3!}\frac{b^2}{2!}\frac{c^1}{1!}\frac{d^1}{1!}\frac{e^2}{2!}\frac{f^1}{1!}\: + \ldots
\end{align}$$

the only thing we need to remember is that there is a factor $10!$ to multiply by for each word of length $10$ and therefore a factor $n!$ for each word length $n$.

In fact since we really only care about the length of the words and not their specific letter content we can replace each letter with a single letter $x$ then when we multiply out our $6$ (now identical) polynomials

$$\left(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6$$

the $x^{10}$ term will receive a contribution from every word type of length $10$, so for example our word type $a^3b^2c^1d^1e^2f^1$ will contribute a coefficient $\frac{1}{3!\,2!\,1!\,1!\,2!\,1!}$.

There will be a similar coefficient for every word type length $10$, all in need of a multiplying factor of $10!$, so if we *actually* take the coefficient of $\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$ instead of $x^{10}$ then this coefficient will be the number of words length $10$ with all our restrictions in place.

In maths notation we say "we take the coefficient of $\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$ in our expanded polynomials" as

$$\left[\frac{x^{10}}{10!}\right]\left(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6$$

In general the number of words length $n$ under those constraints is

$$\left[\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\right]\left(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6$$

This multiplication can be carried out manually (it's easy but tedious) or we can use a computer algebra system such as [sage](http://sagecell.sagemath.org) to do it (you can use [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) too if you like). In any case we get

$$\begin{split}&\left(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6=\\
&\frac{1}{191102976} \, x^{24} + \frac{1}{7962624} \, x^{23} + \frac{13}{7962624} \, x^{22} + \frac{179}{11943936} \, x^{21} + \frac{425}{3981312} \, x^{20} +\\& \frac{617}{995328} \, x^{19} + \frac{9019}{2985984} \, x^{18} + \frac{521}{41472} \, x^{17} + \frac{3739}{82944} \, x^{16} + \frac{485}{3456} \, x^{15} + \frac{41}{108} \, x^{14} +\\& \frac{57}{64} \, x^{13} + \frac{389}{216} \, x^{12} + \frac{149}{48} \, x^{11} + \frac{215}{48} \, x^{10} + \frac{21}{4} \, x^{9} + \frac{19}{4} \, x^{8} + 3 \, x^{7} + x^{6}
\end{split}$$

using the input

```
show(expand((x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24)^6))
```

in sage.

So that the desired coefficient of $\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$ is

$$\frac{215}{48}\cdot 10!=16\,254\,000\tag{Answer}$$

The upshot of this appoach is that to count words of length $n$ from some alphabet of letters, we associate to each letter of the alphabet an *exponential generating function* of the kind

$$\frac{x^{k_1}}{k_1!}+\frac{x^{k_2}}{k_2!}+\ldots +\frac{x^{k_r}}{k_r!}$$

where each term $\frac{x^{k_i}}{k_i!}$ tells us that we are allowed $k_i$ copies of that letter in our words. We then multiply these to obtain our new polynomial from which we take the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ to count valid words with our given restrictions.

---

Using sage we get for the case that we can have 0 of any letters

$$\begin{align}&\left(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6=
\frac{1}{191102976} \, x^{24} + \frac{1}{7962624} \, x^{23} + \frac{13}{7962624} \, x^{22}\\& + \frac{179}{11943936} \, x^{21} + \frac{107}{995328} \, x^{20} + \frac{79}{124416} \, x^{19} + \frac{4757}{1492992} \, x^{18} + \frac{2299}{165888} \, x^{17}\\& + \frac{5857}{110592} \, x^{16} + \frac{3721}{20736} \, x^{15} + \frac{3749}{6912} \, x^{14} + \frac{1691}{1152} \, x^{13} + \frac{6157}{1728} \, x^{12} + \frac{1117}{144} \, x^{11}\\& + \frac{2177}{144} \, x^{10} + \frac{11353}{432} \, x^{9} + \frac{7777}{192} \, x^{8} + \frac{439}{8} \, x^{7} + \frac{1549}{24} \, x^{6} + \frac{259}{4} \, x^{5} + 54 \, x^{4}\\& + 36 \, x^{3} + 18 \, x^{2} + 6 \, x + 1\end{align}$$

In this case there are

$$\frac{2177}{144}\cdot 10!= 54\,860\,400$$

$10$ letter words.

Comment: Wow. What an answer. This will take me some time to go through. Thank you very much. I will go through it tomorrow and accept it once I get the point.

Comment: Okay, please message if you need clarification and I will update as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I probably could write better question. I have written that each letter can occur more than once. I should include that it can also not occur in specific word. I will edit my question.

Comment: Please note I have counted words where there is at least 1 of each letter, if you actually want to count words where some letters can go unused simply add a term $x^0/0!$ I.e. $1$ to each of the $6$ polynomials you are multiplying giving $\left(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6$. If you read the full explanation then it should all make sense, hopefully :)